# How lambda calculus works with an expression like: (Ly.Lt.yt)zx?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I do not understand how to solve this lambda calculus expression:

```
(Lx.yx)((Ly.Lt.yt)zx)
```

I do not understand how `zx` is passed and evalueted.
Is it passed to `Ly` or `Lt` ?
Can you help me?

EDIT:
This is how I tried to solve it:

`(Lx.yx)((Ly.Lt.yt)zx)` I first consider zx as 2 parameters and apply Ly to z:

`->(Lx.yx)((Lt.zt)x)` Then I apply Lt to x and I get:

`->(Lx.yx)(zx)` Now I apply Lx to (zx):

```
->(y(zx))
```

It should be right but I do not undestand well what are the rools in this situation: ((Ly.Lt.yt)zx). What to apply, when to apply and how to apply.
Could you help me please?

Comment: I checked your solution. It is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to ask you what (Ly.Lt.yt) stands for? is it like Lt(Ly(x)) ??

Comment: It expands to `(Ly.(Lt.yt))`.

Answer (score 0):

You always beta-reduce the left most beta reduction possible, which you are doing right. When applying, replace the whole lambda term with the body of the function, except that all occurrences of the function's variable has to be replaced by the argument.

Example:

```
(Lx.Ly.x)(La.Lb.ab)(La.Lb.ba)
[^left most redex^]
(Ly.(La.Lb.ab))(La.Lb.ba)
[^^^^left most redex^^^^]
(Ly.(La.Lb.ab))

(no more beta redexes, done evaluating)
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules are:

- `Lx.Ly.M` means `(Lx.(Ly.M))`.
- `MNP` means `((MN)P)`.

So `((Ly.Lt.yt)zx)` is `(((Ly.(Lt.yt))z)x)`. Thus the first available redex here is `(Ly.(Lt.yt))z`, and all your steps are correct. Well done!